# ADOX error when compiling code with reference to ADOX module

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, ms-access-2007, adox

I get a error with ADOX when compiling, and I don't know what's causing it.

Here is my code:

```
        ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + db + ";" +
            "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");

        MessageBox.Show("Created database" + db + " in current directory " + cDirectory + "\n");
```

---

The error is:

The type or namespace name 'ADOX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

---

How can this error be resolved?

Comment: Please paste the error here.

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ADOX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you trying to open Access 2007 database? Maybe this article can help http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e628d9/creating-retrieving-records-from-m-s-access-2007-using-oledb-in-C-Sharp-net/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your C# project has the following COM reference defined:

> Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security